# Specifying the theme when running ng add @angular/material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli

When running `ng add @angular/material` is it possible to specify which theme we want using a flag / parameter?

I noticed it's possible to run it with `--defaults` which results in the indigo pink theme ...

Comment: `--default` is an option for `ng add` itself - not specific to Angular Material library. You can check `ng add --help`. In theory, `(echo 5 && echo n && echo y) | ng add @angular/material` should work, but I found this works only on the first input, not the rest. It may have to do with the way how `ng add` presents inputs, but this is where I'm stuck right now. Hope someone else can find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme can be set on the command line by using the `theme` option:

`ng add @angular/material  --theme=purple-green`

Comment: Cool!! - Tried it and it works!!  @0xFF Welcome to SO!!